# How to reduce the size of a PDF with embed fonts (Calibri)

Tags: fonts, adobe-indesign, pdf

**I need to reduce a PDF form's size to at least 500 KB from 1,117 KB.**

A client gave me this form already created and they just have to use Calibri as a company standard. I am aware that Calibri is not a standard PDF font and that Acrobat will embed the entire font file and all of its variables in the document. Also the Document Properties window says that the document was created using InDesign.

I already unembedded extra copies of the font under Abobe Optimizer window, and Audit Space Usage is still showing that **the fonts are using 938,717 bytes or 82.14% of all the file size.**

I am thinking about using Helvetica as a last resort as it seems to be the most similar font to Calibri of the 5 standard PDF fonts.

The thing is I, I don't have Helvetica installed in my computer. **Will this cause Acrobat to embed the font anyway?** I guess i'm just trying to figure out this whole font optimizing thing. Am I going to have to download InDesign trial and optimize it from there?

Comment: what are you creating the form in? InDesign, Illustrator, or the dreaded Word? if it's the adobe products why not outline the text?

Comment: @BrianC I am using Acrobat Pro XI. How would I outline the text in Acrobat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In Acrobat, choose `File > Save As Other > Optimized PDF...`
- On the Fonts tab, be sure that "Subset all embedded fonts" is checked.
- Save the PDF.

That will remove all the unused embedded characters, and will substantially reduce the size of the PDF. (As a note, since Calibri is pretty much ubiquitous, you could probably unembed it completely without a problem, since Reader will use the system font when opening the form.)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to lessen the font size by using [Cufon site](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/).

Also, you can remove symbols via [FontForge](http://fontforge.org/).